# Problem with pixelation when copying an illustrator logo to photoshop as a smart object and exporting for web as a png

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator

I'm having issues since I upgraded my CS Suite with copying vector files to photoshop as a smart object and then saving for web as a png 24. The files look quite pixelated even though they are sharp in illustrator. The file is 152x152 pixels at 72dpi.

I've tried:

1. Ticking anti-alias
2. Changing my settings in illustrator for file handling
3. Copying the file as a much larger size to the clipboard in photoshop

Answer (score 1):

Temporarily save as a 608x608, 288 dpi image and then scale it down to 152x152, 72dpi.  This should smooth/blur the jaggy pixelated transitions.

Answer (score 0):

The way I do.
I haven't tried smart object from Illustrator but if I want to use such elements from illustrator, I do following steps.

- Save in Adobe Illustrator by clicking `Ctrl+Shift+S` in desired resolution "dpi".

  Open it in Adobe Photoshop and resize it in desired resoltion by clicking  `Alt+Ctrl+I`.
  .
  *Note : You must save image file without background*

Let me know if this works.

Answer (score 0):

You may have resolved the issue already but I wanted to post anyway since i found this forum first. 
The pixelation problem can be resolved by checking the box "Anti-alias" (shown here in light-blue). Paste the image > select Smart Object or Pixels > check the box Anti-alias.

This issue plagued me for months... especially since 1 out of 2 computers at work had the problem. I suspected that the issue was related to some settings, and i found the answer on a different forum:[image]

Comment: Hey ROI! Welcome to GD.SE! It looks like in the original question they did try checking Anti-alias and it didn't work for them. Any other ideas?